# ssh: Could not resolve hostname rsa: Temporary failure in name resolution in Github workflow

Tags: github, ssh, github-actions

I've recently set up a GitHub workflow and encountered an issue. I've provided both the script and the error message below. Could you please help me with this? I tried multiple way but issue was not solved.

**Script:**

```
name: Deploy to Production

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up SSH key
        uses:  webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.WORD_SECRETS }}

      - name: Deploy to server
        run: |
          ssh -i ${{ secrets.WORD_SECRETS }} ubuntu@131.25.46.231 << EOF
          cd /var/www/test.hopto.org
          git pull origin main 
          # Additional deployment steps if needed
          EOF
```

**Error code:**

```
ssh -i ***
  
  *** ubuntu@13.235.16.99 << EOF
  cd /var/www/brainstormtest.hopto.org
  git pull origin main 
  # Additional deployment steps if needed
  EOF
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh-XXXXXXhwekkp/agent.1739
    SSH_AGENT_PID: 1740
Warning: Identity file -----BEGIN not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rsa: Temporary failure in name resolution
Error: Process completed with exit code 255
```

I'd appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: What do you want to do? As I understand it, you can use the webfactory/ssh-agent to check out other repositories that require SSH access in the action process.